# SKProductRequest returning SSErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey 404

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am making a SKProductRequest using MKStoreKit (v5). I am making an SKProductRequest for a product that has already been approved in the app store, but I am getting an error. Specifically:

```
Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=109 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x171262140 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store, SSErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=404
```

What's confusing me the most is the `SSErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey 404`. The product/IAP has been created in itunes connect. I also have logged out of my personal itunes store account. I'm fairly certain it is making the request to sandbox itunes because I have MITM'd and it makes the request there. However, the request fails because of SSL issues when MITM'd.

EDIT: The product identifiers made using the `SKProductsRequest` are definitely approved and definitely match the product identifiers in iTunes Connect

Comment: How did you eventually solve your issue?

Comment: Getting this again today. Anyone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I spoke with Apple's high level support extensively about the issue. Apparently on older versions of iTunes Connect you could make the bundle id's of apps the same if they never got approved. There were several apps in the account and one had the same bundle id as the app in question. After changing the app bundle id it all worked.

What's interesting is that iTunes Connect no longer allows you to select the same bundle id (explicit) as another app even if it is not approved. Another interesting point is the apps had the same bundle id's since 2010. Not sure what caused this issue to surface up now.

Also, we weren't able to submit with this issue. Once this was fixed, we were able to submit. The reps at Apple said they had never seen anything like this. It's probably because so few apps that were relevant in 2010–when the old iTunes Connect interface was around to allow this type of a bug–are still relevant.

After a good week of banging my head against my keyboard, everything is fixed and in good working order.

Answer (score 0):

## Simulator

Simulator > Reset Content and Settings... > Reset

## Device

Settings App > iTunes & App Store > `your account` > Sign Out

---

## MKStoreKit Tutorial

Create a sample project with which you can try out your In App Purchase setup. Give to that project the same identifier as the current one, so that you can verify your setup.

**Podfile**

```
 pod 'MKStoreKit'
```

**Bridging-Header**

```
#import "MKStoreManager.h"
```

**MKStoreKitConfigs.plist**

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Non-Consumables</key>
        <array>
                <string>com.swiftarchitect.consumable</string>
        </array>
        <key>SharedSecret</key>
        <string>8bac1a72e7f91c48123273b0a6d5ec09</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
    let sk = MKStoreManager.sharedManager()
    print("\(sk)")
```

**Xcode > Target > Capabilities**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

404 is a network error and it says "Cannot connect to iTunes Store". Are you on a simulator? a device? do you have a firewall? network problems? can the app access network in general?

Answer (score 0):

I just experimented this issue. My app was accepted and available on the AppStore, but In App Purchase were missing

When running on Xcode, I was gettings the error `SSErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey 404` since my app was accepted (not before)

After investigation I think I found the solution: for **first** IAP, the in-app purchase should be added on the Application page (iTunes Connect > My App > App version > and then "In app purchases" in the right panel (just under "General Informations")

[image: Add your IAP here]

I'm currently posting the app, I'll post an edit here if it worked.